# Bind dynamic values to progress bar inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, progress-bar, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having an angular progress bar  inside ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="item in result">
   <progressbar  animate="false" value="item.status" type="success"><b>{{item.status}}%</b></progressbar></div>
```

But I'm getting result variable as

```
 $scope.result=[
    {
        id: 0,
        name: "Abc",
        status: "InProgress"
    },
    {
        id: 0,
        name: "Abc",
        status: "InHold"
    }
]
```

How can I assign a particular number to the variable "value " inside progress bar depending upon my JSON data(status).
ie., if status is InProgress value can be 30. Simply I want `value` conditionally based on the status.

Any help will really be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: So where do actual progress values come from?

Comment: Those values I' need to mock in the controller or DOM.But How? Say the value for InPrgoress is 30 if {{item.status}} is "InProgress" and if {{item.status}} is "InHold" then value is 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write one more function which returns `value` based on status.

Like this

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in result">
   <progressbar  animate="false" value="getStatusValue(item.status)" type="success"><b>{{item.status}}%</b></progressbar></div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.result=[
    {
        id: 0,
        name: "Abc",
        status: "InProgress"
    },
    {
        id: 0,
        name: "Abc",
        status: "InHold"
    }
]

$scope.getStatusValue(st) {
     if(st == "InProgress") {
          return 30;
     }
     else if(st == "InHold") {
          return 10;
     }
}
```

It will work.